# How did the propulsion system of George Jetson's car work?

Tags: the-jetsons

George Jetson motored around in a hovercraft. Its motor made a distinctive staccato sound while it was moving. I'm specifically inquiring as to **whether there was any explanation for how the propulsion system (and braking system) worked?**  If so, what was the explanation?

[image]

Comment: Very well, thank you.

Comment: The Jetsons Wikia doesn't provide any useful information about this (it doesn't have any information about the car at all actually...)

Comment: @CodeMed I think the problem with your question is that it is just a bit too broad

Comment: The real question is how the car folds itself into a briefcase.

Comment: I've edited the question now - sorry about not including the pic but I'm on my iPad!

Comment: This question is fine, it could have been explained in an episode or in writers notes somewhere. There's nothing wrong with it and since we allow other comics/superhero stuff here it's appropriate. Don't delete it and don't feel bad because others downvoted it, I've had plenty of downvotes on my questions or answers that I thought were fine. +1

Comment: Even though it hovers and is a craft, I don't think you should call this thing a "hovercraft".  A hovercraft is something else, a vehicle that uses fans to inflate a skirt in order to hover just above the ground.  While I haven't watched the show in years, I believe they just called their family vehicle a "car".

Comment: Isn't the answer just Sprockets? I swear there is a quote that everything in the Jetsons Universe is run on sprockets (or inferior Cogswell Cogs).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the beginning of the episode ["Rosey's Boyfriend"](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2xz5i1), Judy is wearing a "carry belt" that allows her to float through the air, and after she grabs her "geometry tapes" and begins to float downwards, her date Booster says "you always got to adjust the anti-gravity, Judy!" So some form of anti-gravity technology seems to exist in the Jetsons world, we might reasonably speculate it's what holds the cars aloft. But some other technology besides antigravity may be responsible for accelerating them forward, as evidenced by what looks like a stream of exhaust emitted by Booster's car when he is traveling quickly in that first episode, followed by what look like smoke rings when he is just idling, whereas no exhaust of any kind seems to be emitted by Judy's belt. This is also supported by the episode ["Jane's Driving Lesson"](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2ynjem), where Jane is learning to drive and her instructor tells her to first "press the solar starter button" and then "release the antigravity switch on your left". Then after they cut to a comment by the owner of the driving school, the next shot shows the car hovering a few feet off the ground, again with no exhaust being emitted, and then the driving instructor says "now push the accelerator forward" and when Jane does this, it causes the car to start moving horizontally, emitting exhaust as it goes (also note that the staccato sound you mentioned is only heard when the car is moving horizontally, not when it's hovering, and the same goes for Booster's car in 'Rosey's Boyfriend'). Also, in the episode ["The Space Car"](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2xr4dg_the-jetsons-s01e04-the-space-car_tv), about six and a half minutes in when the criminal "Knuckles Nuclear" is getting ready to rob a bank, he asks his girlfriend to hand him the "baby gas gun" (which emits a gas that regresses anyone who breathes it to the mental state of a baby), and then tells her to "keep the jets percolatin'" while she waits in the flying car, so that probably suggests some kind of jet propulsion (unless it's just a slangy way of telling her to be ready to leave at any moment). That doesn't necessarily mean it works like a modern jet engine though, since technically [jet propulsion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_propulsion) refers generally to "thrust produced by passing a jet of matter (typically air or water) in the opposite direction to the direction of motion", so it includes rockets as well as jet engines.

Some more speculations on the Jetsons cars, with plenty of quotes from various episodes, can be found in [this article](http://www.caranddriver.com/features/what-would-george-jetson-drive-feature) from Car and Driver Magazine. The article notes that in "The Space Car" George tells Jane that a particular button activates the "horizontal power cluster", supporting the idea that horizontal acceleration depended on a separate system from vertical lift. It also points out that in ["Jetson's Nite Out"](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2xr1t4) the car is said to rely on "fuel pellets", and that when George goes to a self-service station he asks the computer there for "two bucks’ worth of high-octane pellets, and check the radium", with the use of radium (a radioactive element) possibly suggesting some kind of nuclear power or propulsion system on the car, although it could be for some other high-tech use. Also note that in this episode, running out of fuel pellets causes the car to drop out of the sky so George has to activate the "safety chute", implying that if antigravity is what holds the car up, the fuel pellets must be required to power it.